# How to create a sidebar in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have purchased the Disputo theme that doesn't display any sidebars.
I want to keep my theme but display the sidebar on the home page.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit sidebar from appearance > widget. in order display sidebar you have to choose sidebar template from page edit. there will be changes according to different themes , but this works for most of the themes out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no sidebar option then you can put this code on function.php file

```
/**
 * function.php
 */
function wpdocs_theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'textdomain' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'textdomain' ),
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpdocs_theme_slug_widgets_init' );
```

**Then put this code index.php for showing output**

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) { ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```